# How do I write a linq query against a ListCollectionView?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm, listcollectionview

none of these seem to do the trick:

```
var source = myViewModel.MyListCollectionView.Select(x => x as MyType);
var source = myViewModel.MyListCollectionView.Select<object, MyType>(x => x as MyType);
var source = myViewModel.MyListCollectionView.SourceCollection.Select<object, MyType>(x => x as MyType);
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`ListCollectionView` only implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface. I *suspect* you want:

```
var source = myViewModel.MyListCollectionView.Cast<MyType>();
```

or (if some values won't be of `MyType`, and that's okay):

```
var source = myViewModel.MyListCollectionView.OfType<MyType>();
```

Comment: Minor note: OfType will also remove null items.

Answer (score 7):

```
var source = myViewModel.MyListCollectionView.OfType<MyType>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `InternalList` property is of type `IList` so you would be able to write a `linq` query against that.

Comment: actually   var source = myViewModel.MyListCollectionView.InternalList.Select(x=>x.MyProperty);doesn't work

Comment: This is the non generic IList so you would still have to use Cast<>.  Not to mention that this is a protected property and you couldn't access it unless you were extending ListCollectionView

Answer (score 2):

ahhhh found it. you have to use Cast<> first!

```
var source = myViewModel.MyListCollectionView.Cast<MyType>().Select(p=>p.MyProperty);
```